# Thumbnail hover zoom (enlarge) w/CSS3 and javascript z-axis problem

Tags: javascript, css, hover, zooming, scale

Im attempting to build a series of thumbnails that enlarge on hover. My preliminary build accomplishes the enlarge/zoom part by using CSS3 transform:scale and ease-in-out. The problem is that they overlap each other because they share a single z-axis.

Can anyone assist me in creating a javascript addition to this scenario that correctly positions each thumbnail in a z-axis that makes sense, i.e. each enlarged image resizes to be on top of each other image.

**Demonstration on my website here:** [**demo**](http://nutnics.com/so/hover-zoom.php) Updated: **Solved**

Preview of code:

**html:**

```
<div style="position: absolute;" class="item hover"> 
 <a href="#"><img alt="two" src="img/posts.png"></a> 
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#main div.hover {
position: relative;
z-index:200;
display: block;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
background-color: #297ab1;}

#main div.hover:hover, #main div.hover_effect {
-webkit-transform:scale(1.5, 1.5);
-moz-transform:scale(1.5, 1.5);
-o-transform:scale(1.5, 1.5);
-ms-transform:scale(1.5, 1.5);
transform:scale(1.5, 1.5);}
```

**script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hover').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');
    });
});
```

So this page uses this script to toggle the hover_effect class that increases the div's scale to 150%.

Solution: `z-index:999`

Also any ideas about putting a delay in the initial mouseenter without a setTimeOut?

Any suggestions and solutions are most appreciated!

p.s. This demo uses a modified version of masonry image gallery.

Thanks.

Comment: you can remove the `z-index` property from `#main div.hover` and set the one on `#main div.hover:hover, #main div.hover_effect` to `0` or `1` to simplify your code, using 999 is a bit silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
#main div.hover:hover, #main div.hover_effect {
    z-index: 999
}
```

Comment: Argh, sometimes the easiest solution is right in front of your face. When you stare at stuff for too long you miss the little things. It works perfectly thank you.

Any ideas about a delay on initial mouseenter so they dont enlarge instantly?

Comment: Maybe the [hoverIntent jQuery plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) will help? Though, I'm not sure how easy it will be to make that work with what you already have..

Comment: @nutnics use a keyframe animation which does nothing for a few tenths of a second to produce a delayed animation