# How to change size of images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to enlarge picture when user hovers to images and reduce the size of images after user mouseout the images.

I have the following codes

```
$('#image_layout').on('hover','img',function(){
    $(this).css('width','110%');
})

$('#image_layout').on('mouseout','img',function(){
    $(this).css('width','90%');
})
```

I want to enlarge the image from the center position of the image not from the top lefe position of the image.

The one I have:

```
 ----        ------
|    |  ->  |      |
 ----       |      |
             ------
```

The one I want: (enlarge the picture from center of the image)

```
               ------
   ----       |      | 
  |    |  --> |      |
   ----       |      |
               ------
```

I am not sure how to achieve this. Any tips? Thanks a lot!

Comment: use CSS3 transition property to do that

Comment: Will the larger image still fit inside a larger outer div or do you want it to break out of the bounds of that containing div?  If the answer is to keep it inside a containing div then you can align it vertically via CSS, if the answer to break out then you need to adjust the top of the larger image.

Comment: the CSS3+JavaScript approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085879/thumbnail-hover-zoom-enlarge-w-css3-and-javascript-z-axis-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not as easy as it seems. If you want to keep your origin in the center of the container you need to absolute position the image relative to the container. Try with this lil' plugin, it probably won't work for every case but it's worth a try.

```
$.fn.centerIt = function(){

    var height = this.outerHeight(),
        width = this.outerWidth();

    this.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '50%',
        left: '50%',
        marginTop: -(height/2),
        marginLeft: -(width/2)
    })
    .parent()
    .css('position', 'relative');

    return this;    
};

$('img').css('width', '90%').centerIt();
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/RMsSh/

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using JavaScript for tasks that can be handled by simple CSS tweaks, don't make the weight of JavaScript on your page heavy.

```
#image_layout 
{
   width : /* initial width value */ 
   height: /* initial height value */
}


#image_layout : hover
{
   width : /* new width value */ 
   height: /* new height value */
   /* use of multiple tranistions */
   transition : all 0.2s ease-out 
}
```

Regarding the jQuery way,no need to apply .css() twice, just pass to it an object containing the properties with their values :

```
$('#image_layout').on('mouseout','img',function(){
    $(this).css({'width':'90%', 'height':'100%'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you change the `width` and you haven't defined the `height` yet, the browser automatically keeps the proportion between them, so the `height` will also be `110%` and `90%`.

Try this code:

```
$('#image_layout').on('hover','img',function(){
    $(this).css('width','110%')
        .css('height','100%')
});
$('#image_layout').on('mouseout','img',function(){
    $(this).css('width','90%')
        .css('height','100%');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing image size in JQuery is pretty easy. You can take this or the CSS approach with .CSS()

```
$('#imageId').width(150).height(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the image centered horizontally and vertically in order to do that.